# CentOS 8: dnf upgrade returns several conflicts that I can't seem to resolve

Tags: centos, upgrade, dnf

I've been trying to resolve conflicts in dnf for the past 2 hours.

I followed the instructions to upgrade CentOS 7 to CentoOS 8.

However when I try to run the dnf upgrade, I get all sorts of conflicts: https://pastebin.com/tpTW8Qyk (**updated on 31/Aug/21**)

Errors seems to start when I try to remove the old Kernel:

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo rpm -e `rpm -q kernel`
error: Failed dependencies:
        kernel >= 3.10.0-384.el7 is needed by (installed) hypervkvpd-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.x86_64
```

So I removed the `hypervkvpd` package, hoping that I will be able to install again without issues.

Then I tried the EPL repository upgrade also return more errors:

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                       32 MB/s |  10 MB     00:00    
CentOS-8 - openlogic packages for x86_64                                            646 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                              6.2 MB/s | 798 kB     00:00    
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
CentOS-8 - Updates                                                                  0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                 35 MB/s | 8.3 MB     00:00    
CentOS-8 - Extras                                                                   1.6 MB/s | 9.9 kB     00:00    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'base', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates', ignoring this repo.
```

And it is all downhill from here. I've been looking for hours for information on how to fix those conflicts but cannot find anything that helps.

Comment: Did you try to run the upgrade with `--best --allowerasing` as suggested by `dnf`?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I get the following error: `Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: kernel`

Comment: That doesn't at all look at the sort of conflicts that arise when upgrading **the recommended way**. You can't just point the repositories elsewhere and go `dnf update`, do follow the steps given.

Comment: Follow the steps given where??? I follow the steps here: https://netshop-isp.com.cy/blog/how-to-upgrade-centos-7-to-centos-8/

Comment: Lookling at the first line of your pastebin output "'--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade):" could it be that you've not followed the exact commands in the steps, specifically the `dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync` ?

Comment: It might very well be!!! I restored a backup and will try again next weekend.

Comment: @steve I tried the instructions again today. However I get the following errors: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'base', ignoring this repo. Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates', ignoring this repo. So it is all errors from this point onwards. I have updated the paste bin with my latest attempt.

Comment: Possibly same as https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4222851 ?